# Проблема с русскими символами в SpringBoot + Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-ee, spring-boot

application.yml

```
management:
security:
    enabled: false
```

security:
    basic:
        enabled: false

spring:
    datasource:
        default-catalog: library
        jndi-name: jdbc/Library

```
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5MySQLDBDialect
    properties:
        hibernate:
            current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

            format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
```

logging:
    file: c:\temp\app.log
    pattern:
      file: "%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c] - %m%n"

```
level:
    ROOT: error
    org.springframework: warn
    javax.faces: warn
    org.omnifaces: warn
    org.springframework.security: warn
    org.hibernate: warn
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: warn
```

Когда выполняю запрос

```
genreRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByName("д");
```

то ничего не находит, хотя в базе есть имена содержащие букву- Д

а когда выполняю идентичный запрос, только с английскими буквами, то все работает отлично. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить мою проблему?

P.S: я новичек, если нужно еще показать какой-то код, то говорите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю проблема связана с кодировкой.
Вы не приложили конфиг с подключением к своей БД, но забегая вперед попробуйте явно указать кодировку:

```
jdbc:mysql://db_host/db_name?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```